# Need a way to extract and compare the AD Account expiry date

Tags: powershell

I am using the below command to get the account expiry date of an AD-user.

Get-ADUser sisuser -Properties * | Select-Object AccountExpirationDate

I am getting a result what i need. Now, i want to know if the returned date from command falls in next 30 days.

In Simple words i want to know, if an AD account expires in next 30 days or not using Powershell. If yes, write in a log file saying "Account  will expire in  of days".

Comment: if you are running this in a loop that checks _many_ accounts, you likely will get faster results if you filter in your `Get-ADUser` call for something like `"AccountExpirationDate -lt '$30DayAgo'"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply subtract `[datetime]::Today` or `(Get-Date).Date` and
check if  resulting .Days property is less or equal than 30 and
append that boolean as a calculated property.

```
Get-ADUser sisuser -Properties * | Select-Object AccountExpirationDate,
   @{Label='ExpiresNext30Days';Expression={($_.AccountExpirationDate -(Get-Date).Date).Days -le 30}}
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much for the response it is working.

But, i would like to what the expression "@{Label='ExpiresNext30Days';Expression={($_.AccountExpirationDate -(Get-Date).Date).Days -le 30}}" will do.

Apologies i am new to Powershell.

Comment: This appends a new calculated property with a hash table, you either need a `Label='PropertyName'` or `Name='PropertyName'` and an `Expression={}` script block (LabelName/Expression may be shortened to `L/N/E`). Inside the scriptblock you reference the current Items properties with $_.PropertyName.